# Where does this space come from?

Tags: spacing, minipage

Using colored text inside a minipage results in less vertical space being
appended after the text compared to normal text.  Strangely, this only occurs when the minipage is top-aligned.  In the other cases, the space is consistent.

Also, in both cases there is more space compared to text that isn't inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
    #1
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\hrule\relax
\maketitle{\color{blue} Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\maketitle{Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\noindent {\color{blue} Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\noindent Bla.
\hrule\relax
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Add a `%` after `\end{minipage}` in your `\maketitle` definition.

Comment: You get the space because of the spurious space after `\end{minipage}` in your definition. You get *different* spaces as `\color` doesn't switch to hmode and so your minipages have different baselines (add a dot before the `\begin{minipage}` to see it. You can avoid this by using `\noindent` before `#1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a case of the missing `%`, in this case after the `\end{minipage}` in the `\maketitle` definition.

In general, when there is a situation of unwanted space being introduced, the *first* place to look is always the missing `%`. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).

I should note that a number of environments automatically remedy this issue by employing `\ignorespaces` at the end of their definition.  So, in your case, the following definition would also work (note the absence of the `%`):

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
    #1
  \end{minipage}
  \ignorespaces
}
```

Here is the MWE which instead adds a `%`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
    #1
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
\hrule\relax
\maketitle{\color{blue} Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\maketitle{Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\noindent {\color{blue} Bla.}
\hrule\relax

\vskip\bigskipamount

\hrule\relax
\noindent Bla.
\hrule\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't include the detailed explanation *why* the vertical space is here and *why* it is different in the colored and uncolored version and *why* the removing of horizontal space (using `%`) influences the visual vertical space. I try to explain this.

So, the `\maketitle` macro above starts the horizontal mode (see `\noindent`) and first "letter" of this mode is the `\vtop` (the minipage in LaTeX terminology). Then two following spaces are in OP's code. First one after `\vtop` (in macro, it was corrected by Steven using `%`) and second one after right brace from the souce line where `\maketitle` macro is used. After such two spaces the `\hrule` primitive is read. This primitive invokes `\par`, because it is read in horizontal mode. So we have:

```
\vtop{Bla.}\space\space\par
```

The `\par` primitive does one `\unskip`, so we have

```
\vtop{Bla.}\space
```

and this material is assembled to the paragraph. The first "letter" `\vtop` has the width equal to `\hsize`, so this "letter" fills the whole first line. The space is the break point and the second empty line is created (the Underfull hbox is reported in log file). But if only one space exists after `\vtop` in horizontal mode, then this space is removed by `\par` and the whole paragraph has only one line with `\vtop` as a "letter".

Summary: the paragraph has two lines if there are two spaces at its end. If only one (or none) space is here then only one line paragraph is created.

The second question: why colored version generates different vertical space than uncolored. The uncolored version generates

```
\vtop{Bla}
```

and the baseline of this `\vtop` is equal to the baseline of the text Bla. But colored version generates

```
\vtop{\special{color setting}Bla}
```

and the baseline of `\vtop` goes through the `\special`. The text Bla is below the baseline and it consists the depth of the `\vtop` "letter". The second empty line from the two-line paragraph is closer to the text Bla, when this text is below the baseline. Schema:

```
Uncolored version:

    Bla
------------------ baseline of the first line of paragraph

------------------ baseline of the second line of paragraph
---------------------------- hrule

Colored version:

----special------- baseline of the first line of paragraph
    Bla
------------------ baseline of the second line of paragraph
---------------------------- hrule
```